# Php webservice - call parameterised function from browser

Tags: php, web-services, function, parameters

I have 1 function which is having 1 parameter.
   I want to call this function from browser.
   How can I call?
   It is giving me blank.
   When I write same code outside function , it is working.
   Please help me.
   I am passing this link to browser  "domainname ://ipaddress/test.php/mywebservice"

i am using this code :

```
<?php

$json = '{"foo-bar": 12345}';

$obj = json_decode($json);
//print $obj->{'foo-bar'}; // 12345
switch($_GET['function']) {
case 'specificFunction':
    abc();
}

function abc
{
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","uname","Password");

if (!$con)

{

die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());

}
//print_r($con);

mysql_select_db("roster", $con);



$query = "select * from rates";
$rs = mysql_query($query) or die($query);
//print_r($rs);
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($rs)){
$record[] = $row;
}

$data = json_encode($record);

header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo $data;
}
?>
```

Result :

```
{'foo-bar'}; // 12345 switch($_GET['function']) { case 'specificFunction': abc(); } function abc { $con = mysql_connect("localhost","uname","Password"); if (!$con) { die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); } //print_r($con); mysql_select_db("roster", $con); $query = "select * from rates"; $rs = mysql_query($query) or die($query); //print_r($rs); while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($rs)){ $record[] = $row; } $data = json_encode($record); header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate'); header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT'); header('Content-type: application/json'); echo $data; } ?>
```

If I wirte:

```
<?php

$json = '{"foo-bar": 12345}';

$obj = json_decode($json);
//print $obj->{'foo-bar'}; // 12345

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","uname","Password");

if (!$con)

{

die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());

}
//print_r($con);

mysql_select_db("roster", $con);



$query = "select * from rates";
$rs = mysql_query($query) or die($query);
//print_r($rs);
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($rs)){
$record[] = $row;
}

$data = json_encode($record);

header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo $data;

?>

Result :



[{"Month":"July","Year":"2012","Rate":"1.20%","Short":"0.24%","Mid":"0.92%","Long":"2.30%","RateUnFormatted":"0.012","LastUpdated":"2012-09-01 01:00:00","PublishFlag":"M"},{"Month":"June","Year":"2012","Rate":"1.20%","Short":"0.23%","Mid":"1.07%","Long":"2.64%","RateUnFormatted":"0.012","LastUpdated":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","PublishFlag":""},]
```

Which is correct.

Comment: No code => no answer. What is so difficult about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call it from... (let me quote you) "outside function".

e.g.:
page.php:

```
include "file-containing-my-function.php";
$param = $_GET['param'];
myFunction($param);
```

You can use a more general and much less secure method with passing the function name:

With a request looking something like this: `page.php?action=myFunction&param=value`
(or with rewrite engine you can achieve this same URL from a `://domain/page/myFunction/value` request)

page.php:

```
$callback = $_GET['action'];
$param = $_GET['value'];
echo $callback($param);
```

With this method you can call any function from your service with any first or single parameter with just changing the URL. But you also expose everything, so you should secure this request, by either checking the function's name against user privileges, or check privileges in every single function you have. Same goes for the parameter of the function.

**There's no direct way to specify a function to be called from a URL.** You need to implement it for yourself, if you need a functionality like this, just as I did above.

**EDIT:**

I think I see what's your question. Use rewrite engine. Add to your .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*)
RewriteRule ^test.php/(.*)?$ test.php?function=$1&%1 [L]
```

This will rewrite a query like:

**http://domain/page.php/myFunction?param=value**

to

**http://domain/page.php?function=myFunction&param=value**

Note that myFunction can also become "asd/asd/asd" (for a request like "page.php/asd/asd/asd?asd") which is not a callable.

Comment: Sorry to ask silly question...but what should I do?What changes I have to make in my code?

Comment: I am having very less knowledge on php side.

Comment: For instance, close the switch. Other than that, the PHP seems ok. The code I gave in may edit, for the rewrite engine goes to .htaccess. Google it for more information. But you dont need to. Only if you need nice looking URLs. Just simply use **http://domain/page.php?function=myFunction&param=value** to test your script